# Unable to install mjpegtools ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.10

I am trying to install mjpegtools on ubuntu but its giving me the following error:

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Its tring to download some stuff like

```
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/m/mjpegtools/mjpegtools_1.9.0-0.0ubuntu3_i386.deb  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try what the error message suggests and do `sudo apt-get update`

The problem is that your system has outdated package info and wants an older version than the repositories currently contain.